# Authorisation of users in PHP and MYSQL for wifi hotspot

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a wifi system that I am trying to setup using PHP & My SQL auth. I have found this script https://github.com/kaptk2/portal that does all I want. But unfortunately when I try to login I keep getting an error "A valid username or password was not found."

I have setup all of the SQL table's correctly (From the SQL dump provided) and from what i can see in the authorisation.php file (Below) it should be working: 
http://pastebin.com/kHe6EH6T (Sorry cant seem to get the php to format correctly here)

My initial taught on what was going wrong was that the user and pass were being denied because the unix timestamp was incorrect.but then i checked the time on my system and made sure that the value was substantially increased and still the same error. The values that I am using are the following:

- ID: 3
- username: test
- password: test
- expires: 1482135170
- notes: null

I have checked all of the error logs (PHP, apache and Mysql) but there are no errors.

Is there a chance that the error could be happening with the authentication of the controller (On another server) And I cant see it in the logs ?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: For the MySQL in addtion to editing index.php you will need to edit
config.php and create a database. See tables.sql for an example table
layout

Comment: Hi there, I get the following output:     Array ( [username] => test [password] => test [submit] => Submit )

Comment: `md5()` passwords? Would recommend not using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change you code:

```
if ($_POST)
{
  $user = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/", "", $_POST['username']);
  $pass = $_POST['password'];
  if (authorizeMySQL($user, $pass))
        sendAuthorization($_SESSION['id'], '480');
  else
      echo "Cannot connect to mysql.";
}
else
      echo "A valid username or password was not found.";
```

and you probably will see that problem with mysql connection, check its settings in mysql/config.php and check whether the user provided is stored in `guests` table

UPDATE: also note - in mysql you should have passwords stored as MD5, for for test it is `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`

Comment: Thanks Ilya, Now getting Cannot connect to mysql. I have double checked all of the settings and the database is running locally. Do you know where I could look to see what the problem is ? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @user1781267 after `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);` add `print_r($row);die();` and check what is actually taken from db

Comment: Just added       $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result):
print_r($row);die();`
  $t = time(); // Unix time stamp    and I am now getting a blank page  In the log I get PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':' in /var/www/guest/s/default/authorized.php on line 61

Comment: Still getting a blank page, the error now is: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':' in /var/www/guest/s/default/authorized.php on line 61

Comment: ah, replace : with ; after mysql_fetch_row

Comment: Changed to the following and am getting the same error:   $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);die();
  $t = time(); // Unix time stamp

Comment: it is impossible, recheck it twice

Comment: Ok so double checked and am now ussing the following code: http://pastebin.com/73CbhxWK

Comment: ok, so you fetched nothing from db - check my updated answer about password storing

Comment: Ok, just changed the password to the MD5 hash and getting the following string Array ( [0] => 1482135170 ). What does this mean ?